# Conversion of AtomicInteger to int

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I wrote a thread and for memory synchronization I have to use Atomicinteger. Here is my code:

```
public class NewClass implements Runnable {

public double rr;
public double rmse_new;
public double rmse_newT;
private int k;
private int[][] Xdisc;

public NewClass(int Xdisc[][], double[][] pat_cand, int k, double[][] Yresid, double[][] Xresid) {

    this.k = k;
    this.Xdisc = Xdisc;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    final AtomicInteger q = new AtomicInteger(0);
    q.set(0);
    while (true) {
        if (q.incrementAndGet() >= Xdisc.length) {
            break;

            Integer[] temp_X;
            temp_X = new Integer[Xdisc[0].length];
            for (int s = 0; s < Xdisc[0].length; s++) {
                temp_X[s] = Xdisc[q][s];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

the problem is that q is the row index of a 2D array Xdisc (in main class) and apparently should be integer but in NewClass, q is AtomicInteger. Therefore I got this error:

```
incompatible types
required: int
found: AtomicInteger
```

in this line

```
temp_X[s] = Xdisc[q][s];
```

and I even tried

```
temp_X[s] = Xdisc[(int)q][s];
```

and got this error:

```
inconvertible types
```

Is there anyway to convert AtomicInteger to int?

Comment: Your code is currently broken at the moment anyway, as you've got code after a `break` statement - that's unreachable. It's hard to suggest working code when it's broken in ways which have nothing to do with he question.

Comment: Use AtomicInteger.get() (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#get())

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to use an atomic here... you only use it inside a single thread. Atomic classes and volatile are for values that are shared between threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to use the same value throughout the loop, just use the return value of `incrementAndGet()`:

```
int index = q.incrementAndGet();
if (index >= Xdisc.length) {
    break;
} // I'm assuming you meant there to be a brace here...

Integer[] temp_X;
temp_X = new Integer[Xdisc[0].length];
for (int s = 0; s < Xdisc[0].length; s++) {
    temp_X[s] = Xdisc[index][s];
}
```

If you want the absolute latest value, use `get()`.

Comment: As a side note, there's an array index out of bounds at `Xdisc[Xdisc.length]` in the for loop. The `if` condition should be `if (index >= Xdisc.length - 1)` or simply `if (index == Xdisc.length - 1)`.

Comment: @Radiodef: Um, I don't think so. An index of `Xdisc.length - 1` is fine, so we should still go for the loop when `index` has that value. What makes you think we need to stop earlier?

Comment: Right now the while loop stops at `index == Xdisc.length`. The loop basically looks like `while(++index <= Xdisc.length);`

Comment: @Radiodef: Yes, it does. That is, when `index == Xdisc.length` the `for` loop *doesn't* execute - which is correct, because *that* would cause an exception. But it *does* execute when `index == Xdisc.length - 1`, which is also correct, but which wouldn't happen with your suggested code.

Comment: @Radiodef: No, it doesn't look like that while loop - because it *breaks* when `index == Xdisc.length`, before executing the `for` loop... whereas your `while` loop would still execute the entire body when `index == Xdisc.length`.

Comment: Yes you're right I misunderstood the intended logic. The brace is throwing me off. The more clear refactor would be `while (q.incrementAndGet() < Xdisc.length) {`.

Comment: @Radiodef: Except then you'd need to perform an assignment within the `while`, in order to definitely use the same value later. I'm happy enough with it the way it is.

Answer (score 6):

Please use:

```
AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger();
int result = x.intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Atomic-classes is to allow a thread-safe usage of those values through the `compareAndSet()` method or it sub-methods like `incrementAndGet()`, but you are not using the AtomicInteger in a threaded context at all, so replacing it with a standard int would not make any difference (beside running a bit faster).

The reason is that you create the AtomicInteger inside the Runnable, so basically each thread will have its *very own* instance of it.

In general you should read the great documentation for Java classes, it will answer many questions: [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)